# How to execute command stored in file in perl

Tags: perl, command

I want to run this command but not from command line. I want to run file for example first.pl which do some other commands. For example when i run this file I want to do this:

```
perl -ne "print qq{$1\n} if /^\s+ (\w+)/x" file
```

it should be in this file. I try something like this:

```
my $input = "input.txt";
my @listOfFiles = `perl -ne "print qq{$1\n} if /^\s+ (\w+)/x" $input`;
print @listOfFiles;
```

but it print nothing. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Why do you run perl as a separate command, instead of just putting the code directly into the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to run a separate perl command, just do what you want in the main script:

```
open my $file, "input.txt";
my @listOfFiles;
while (<$file>) {
  if (/^\s+ (\w+)/x) {
    push @listOfFiles, $1;
  }
}
close $file;
print "@listOfFiles";
```

Answer (score 3):

Always use `use strict; use warnings;`! You would have gotten

```
Unrecognized escape \s passed through
Unrecognized escape \w passed through
Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string
```

As `$1` is addition to the desired `$input`. So you need to properly escape your argument. Assuming you're not on a Windows system,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $input = "input.txt";
my $cmd = shell_quote('perl', '-ne', 'print "$1\n" if /^\s+ (\w+)/x', $input);
chomp( my @listOfFiles = `$cmd` );
print "$_\n" for @listOfFiles;
```

Comment: … or one could use `open` which would effectively be the same thing: `use autodie; open my $cmd, "-|", @command_with_args; chomp(my @listOfFiles = <$cmd>); close $cmd;`

Comment: I have then error:
`Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.`

Comment: As I pointed out, my solution won't work on Windows. The worst part of Windows is how it passes args to programs. Best off escaping manually: `qx{perl -ne "print \\"$1\n\\" if /^\\s+ (\\w+)/x" "$input"}` (`qx{}` is the same as backticks, but SO makes it hard to use backticks. Feel free to use actual backticks in your code.)

Comment: How can i do it in windows? it is real? 
my $cmd = qx{perl -ne "print \\"$1\n\\" if /^\\s+ (\\w+)/x" "$input"} (qx{});
chomp( my @listOfFiles = `$cmd` );
print "$_\n" for @listOfFiles;

Comment: `chomp( my @listOfFiles = qx{...} );`